# Ionic - How to use two controllers conditionally in one modal

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic project, where I need to use single modal view & conditionally call controller for it.

I am trying to do like following -

```
<div ng-if="!isEditMode" ng-controller="Controller1">
<div ng-if="isEditMode" ng-controller="Controller2">
    <ion-content>
        <!-- My view code  -->
    </ion-content>
</div>
</div>
```

here, both controller are get called(can see console in controller). but html page not get rendered just white screen appear. 
If I remove controller2 then it works fine with just one controller.

Comment: where does isEditMode stored? in controler1 or controller2?

Comment: This sounds like the wrong approach.  Is it the case then that you have two states with this view; one for editing and one for not?  If so, it sounds like two separate routes.

Comment: In controller from where I am opening this modal. condition is working fine,  I have cross checked it.

Comment: @Makoto This is modal not state, I am also thinking to create another html for same modal.

Comment: That happens because of nested HTML, Try writing two separate divs.